# Finding a vector within a specified range of angles from other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, angle

Take $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is there a way of finding some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, given the inequalities $l_i\leq\theta_i\leq u_i$ where $\theta_i$ is the angle between $x$ and $v_i$, or proving that such an $x$ exists?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you give a bit more background on the reason for your question. Why do you need this? What do you want to do with this? Are the various numbers $l_i , u_i$ random, fixed or related and the same for the vectors. Are you looking for a numerical answer/method or something analytical? Without knowledge of any of these thing it not possible to give a good answer.

In the general case without additional information one can only try and find a vector ${\bf x}$ in a systematic fashion. This can be done more efficiently by analysing the set of vectors ${\bf v}_i$ in detail, for instance if there is an $1 \leq i<j \leq k$ such that $\arccos({\bf v}_i \cdot {\bf v}_j) >u_i + u_j$ there is no ${\bf x}$ that can satisfy all the constraints. In particular the small $u_i$ are relevant for such an approach.

A very simple method would be to generate random points on a unit sphere that represent the direction of ${\bf x}$ and check whether they satisfy all of the constraints. The disadvantage is of course that if you do not find a good direction, you still don't know whether it exist or not.

In a more systematic way you need to consider ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_1$ and find the area on the unit sphere that is allowed by their simultaneous constraints. Successively adding more ${\bf v}_i$ will diminish the area on the unit sphere that is allowed. The process stops whenever the area completely vanishes, or you run out of vectors ${\bf v}_i$. Problematic here is the fact that the area most likely will consists of various disjoint parts of the unit sphere each of which is bounded by a subset of the set of constraints. Alternatively, one could make imperfect representation of the allowed area by a discretisation of the unit sphere, for instance a fine triangulation mesh, and keep track of which of the triangles is completely allowed and which ones are intersected by one or more constraints.

Comment: I know it's a fairly routine response on SE to state that you need more information, but I've supplied everything necessary here. Knowing why I'm asking this would not help in answering it, and you shouldn't assume anything about how the inequalities are generated or what special relationships there may be between them. If there were any, I would have stated them. I would have thought asking for a proof of the existence of $x$ would imply I'm seeking an analytical answer but maybe I should have been more explicit. Anyway, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: No problem, but if it is a fully general problem you can't really expect an analytic answer on the question wether there is or is not a possible vector that satisfies all the constraints. Essentially, you could reformulate this into a set of inequalities in $x_i$ as being used in linear programming (except that it will have some non-linearity included) for which you in general cannot see in advance whether there is a solution either until you are left with a non-empty  bounded volume to search in.